# Dragging a circle using rafael.js - code example

Tags: javascript, svg, rafaeljs

I was trying to find the source code for [this](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag) rafael.js example but on the page the link is broken.

Could someone give the simplest source code example that demonstrates how one can use the mouse to drag a circle using rafael.js ? Just like in the linked example ?

Comment: I've found one example: http://jsfiddle.net/BmLLh/56/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the source itself at http://raphaeljs.com/reference.js, at L133 you find the relevant example...

```
   (function (r) {
        var x, y;
        r.circle(15, 15, 10).attr(fill).drag(function (dx, dy) {
            this.attr({
                cx: Math.min(Math.max(x + dx, 15), 85),
                cy: Math.min(Math.max(y + dy, 15), 85)
            });
        }, function () {
            x = this.attr("cx");
            y = this.attr("cy");
        });

    })(prepare("Element.drag-extra"))
```

Removing dependencies and refactoring to make it—in my humble opinion—clearer, you get...

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var x, y;

paper.circle(15, 15, 10).attr("fill", "red").drag(
  function (dx, dy) {
    this.attr("cx", x + dx);
    this.attr("cy", y + dy);
  }, 
  function () {
    x = this.attr("cx");
    y = this.attr("cy");
  }
);
```

You can find the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ke1Ltbft/1/

I personally prefer to refactor the code a bit...

```
paper.circle.drag(start, move, end)

function start(x, y) {
  // mouse/touch start code
}

function move(dx, dy) {
  // mouse/touch move code
}

function end(x, y) {
  // mouse/touch end code
}
```